How to pronounce the cigar brand Cohiba in Spanish
Is it Co-ee-va? The h is silent, and the b between the two vowels is a soft b that's in between the sound of b and v?

I think that in Spain is Co-e-ba. There is practically no distinction in how we pronounce ba and va. I don't know why you duplicated the e.

@RubioRic the duplicated "e" seems like mapping a Spanish "i" into a similar sounding English "ee" as in "keep, sheep, deep" etc, vs a single English "e" as in "let, vet, debt"

@PeterM I know, I know. Too many languages. Thanks!

La pronunciación, usando el IPA chart es:
/koiβa/
Para tener un ejemplo, esta es similar a la pronunciación de la palabra cohibamos:
En este video de youtube mencionan la marca. La pronunciación es por un Español, que no es muy distinta de la latinoamericana.
Finalmente, mi pronunciación, en el siguiente audio:

